# Rotated and deformed object detect by template on python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, augmented-reality, fiducial-markers

I am a python beginner, we have a project where we need to detect and crop out the desired pattern from a photo:

This is the original picture:

[image: This is the original picture]

Each picture has such a regular border, but it is not closed, in order to detect the direction (similar to a QR code)

[image: 2]

The image to be detected is taken by a mobile phone and may be deformed, rotated and scaled,  we need to get the pattern in the middle of the box:

[image: image1]  [image: image2]  [image: image3]

My code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import math

def getdistance(p1,p2):
    v1=np.array(p1)
    v2=np.array(p2)
    v3=v2-v1
    v4=math.hypot(v3[0],v3[1])
    return v4

img_object = cv.imread('small.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img_scene = cv.imread('img2.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

if img_object is None or img_scene is None:
    print('Unable to read image!')
    exit(0)
minHessian = 400
detector = cv.SIFT_create()
keypoints_obj, descriptors_obj = detector.detectAndCompute(img_object, None)
keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene = detector.detectAndCompute(img_scene, None)
img_2 = cv.drawKeypoints(img_scene,keypoints_scene,img_scene)

matcher = cv.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv.DescriptorMatcher_FLANNBASED)
knn_matches = matcher.knnMatch(descriptors_obj, descriptors_scene, 2)

ratio_thresh = 0.95
good_matches = []
for m,n in knn_matches:
    if m.distance < ratio_thresh * n.distance:
        good_matches.append(m)

img_matches = np.empty((max(img_object.shape[0], img_scene.shape[0]), img_object.shape[1]+img_scene.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
cv.drawMatches(img_object, keypoints_obj, img_scene, keypoints_scene, good_matches, img_matches, flags=cv.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)

obj = np.empty((len(good_matches),2), dtype=np.float32)
scene = np.empty((len(good_matches),2), dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(len(good_matches)):
    obj[i,0] = keypoints_obj[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt[0]
    obj[i,1] = keypoints_obj[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt[1]
    scene[i,0] = keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt[0]
    scene[i,1] = keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt[1]
H, _ =  cv.findHomography(obj, scene, cv.RANSAC)

obj_corners = np.empty((4,1,2), dtype=np.float32)
obj_corners[0,0,0] = 0
obj_corners[0,0,1] = 0
obj_corners[1,0,0] = img_object.shape[1]
obj_corners[1,0,1] = 0
obj_corners[2,0,0] = img_object.shape[1]
obj_corners[2,0,1] = img_object.shape[0]
obj_corners[3,0,0] = 0
obj_corners[3,0,1] = img_object.shape[0]
scene_corners = cv.perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, H)

q1=(int(scene_corners[0,0,0]), int(scene_corners[0,0,1]))
q2=(int(scene_corners[1,0,0]), int(scene_corners[1,0,1]))
q3=(int(scene_corners[2,0,0]), int(scene_corners[2,0,1]))
q4=(int(scene_corners[3,0,0]), int(scene_corners[3,0,1]))
dist=getdistance(q1, q2)
disti=int(dist)
print('q1: %s, q2: %s, q3: %s, q4: %s, dist: %s'%(q1, q2, q3, q4, dist))
src_points = np.array([q3, q4, q1, q2], dtype = "float32")
dst_points = np.array([[disti,disti], [0, disti], [0, 0], [disti, 0]], dtype = "float32")
M = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(src_points, dst_points)
perspective = cv.warpPerspective(img_scene, M, (disti, disti), cv.INTER_LINEAR)
_, result = cv.threshold(perspective, 0, 255,cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)
cv.imshow('result', result)
cv.waitKey()
```

I have researched for a long time, but the results are still not ideal. I would like to ask if there are better ideas to achieve our needs?

Comment: scrap the SIFT/features approach. I'm untagging SIFT because that's not helping at all (would if you were trying to match against the texture _in_ the frame, not the frame itself) -- qr codes have finder patterns designed to be detected cheaply. this thing here may not be as trivial. you'll have to detect squares/quads that are "connected" by bars... and the fourth corner is tricky on top of that. if you find its contour, it will have an obvious convexity defect (good to recognize it)

Comment: after knowing where the patterns are, you'll want to employ **subpixel edge refinement** as used in aruco/apriltag/generic AR tags, to calculate **corners** from subpixel-localized (straight) edges and their intersections. locating corners directly will be noisy and biased. -- _later_ I might spend some time investigating your question further

Comment: I know that my thinking is wrong, but I don't know how to do it, I don't know how to develop Python finder patterns designed to be detected, I hope some friends can give me some code examples,  i would be very grateful!

Comment: something easier to detect would be a solid frame, not broken up like you showed. a particular color (hue) _may_ also be helpful, but _not_ if that affects contrast. contrast is most important. solid square, findContours with *no approximation/simplification*, approxPolyDP *to find the corners only*, split the original contour by those corner points to obtain the points on each of four edges, then fit lines through each, then intersect them, to get reasonably good corner estimates. next, getPerspectiveTransform and warpPerspective